# Pass meteor data to dynamic react children

Tags: reactjs, meteor-react

I am using Meteor and React. I am also using getMeteorData() (yes I know mixins may be dead one day). The data is fine in the component loading it, but I want to pass it (or a subset of it) along with other props to dynamic children like so:

```
content = Children.map(this.props.children, child => {
  console.log('Test: ', this.data.testData) //<- this logs the expected data
  let test = this.data.testData 
  return cloneElement(child, {
    ...child.props, //<- THIS IS OK
    ...this.props, //<- THIS IS OK
    data: this.data, //<-- THIS DOES NOT SHOW UP IN THE CHILD
    testData: {test} //<-- THIS DOES NOT SHOW UP IN THE CHILD
  })
})
```

What am I missing and/or how can I pass meteor data down with other props to dynamic children?

TIA